# Calling a decorator from another view

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I have a decorator defined in users/views.py and I want to use the same in profile/views.py in django

Decorator function in users/views.py

```
def is_active_consult(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            usrid = request.session['id']
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=usrid)
            usercons =    Userconsultation.objects.get(doctor=user.doctor,status='InProgress')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            usercons = ''

        if usercons:
            url = '/encounter_notes/'+str(usercons.userconsultationid)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

When I try to import like

```
from users.views import is_active_consult
```

It gives an import error "cannot import name is_active_consult"

Is it right to define a decorator in a view, if not where do I put it and for now how do I fix the issue.

Regards

Comment: Could you post the traceback you're getting with the error? Might be that you have some kind of import loop in there, but that's just a very wild guess. Other than that, though, it should be perfectly valid. In any case, personally, I prefer to define decorators in a module called `decorators` in my Django apps, but that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to import this?

Comment: My best guess is that your package structure isn't set up correctly...

Comment: You know you can edit your question and post the entire traceback there, do you? That bit of code you dropped into a comment does not help at all, since there doesn't seem to be any import involved in it. Without getting some more detailed information about what exactly went wrong, I don't see how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator is a function like any other so you can define it wherever you want to, the problems is not the decorator but the import itself: import loop, incorrect path or not set, etc.

1) Did you succeed in importing anything from users/views.py to profile/views.py ?

2) Can you paste your project structure ? ( # ls -R)

Comment: Hi Saksow, I put a common decorator module and that fixed the issue as of now. Also I was able to import some other methods easily. So not sure. But I have proceeded further as I mentioned because that seems to be the right way, anyways. Thank you for your assistance.